# How to filter an array of words in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I filter an array of words in Microsoft Excel? For example, I have a big list of road names in Singapore and I wish to filter all entries in the Excel containing any road name in the list. How do I do that?

Comment: Please, edit your question to include examples of the list and the format of the text you need to filter. You will get better answers if you show some effort by posting what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

- Turn filtering on (Home tab -> Sort & Filter -> Filter).
- Click the dropdown next to your column containing the road names.
- Text Filters -> Contains...
- Type the road name you want to match and click OK.